# Using bootstrap in HTML5 template

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can we use bootstrap in an already made HTML5 template without changing the structure of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which functionality you want to use. But if you are planning to use responsive grid, and you didn't use similar grid in HTML before, then the answer is no.

If you already used similar grid (grid that uses classes to specify breakpoints), then you could theoretically rename classes in bootstrap to match your own classes.

Comment: I am using a template with pure css structure. No Bootstrap grid. I just want to use bootstrap for navbar. Can it be done?

Comment: It really depends on you template/HTML, but the chances are very low. Because HTML structure of your navigation should be very similar/same to the one used in Bootrstrap's navigation

Comment: Ya but there is no Navigation bar in the template and I want to use a bootstrap navigation for that.

Comment: In that case you will have to edit HTML. Sorry but there simply isn't a workaround for that.
Why can't you just edit HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and use in your project only what you really need.

Check in the documentation which [JavaScript plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-navbar-js) you need and how to change [the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-navbar-breakpoint).